# A design dilemma when working with factory classes

Tags: objective-c, oop, factory, factory-pattern

In my app I have multiple subclasses of `UITableViewCell`. I use a factory class to instantiate the right type and provide them to whoever needs them. The factory class gets an argument which is a data object that represents the cell. I consider that to be alright since the factory is part of the controller.

`Cellfactory* factory = [[Cellfactory alloc ] initWithData:data];`

The problem comes when that data object is mapped with its view representation inside the factory class. I've thought of 2 solutions:

- to keep a dictionary with the mapping, the keys would be a string representation of the data object class and the value would be a string representation of the view class responsible for rendering that data object. That way when the factory is asked to provide a view based on a data object, it will know what class to instantiate by looking into the map dictionary. The down side is that if you add another data object, you need to modify the factory method too (add a new entry in its dictionary)
- a more flexible solution that would not require to modifying the factory method no matter how many new objects you add, would be to keep the name of the view class responsible for rendering the data object inside the data object itself. But that couples the model to the view and somehow doesn't feel right for the model to have to provide info regarding the rendering.

So, which of these two are a better long term alternative? Is there any other alternative that beats them both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something similar to [NSValueTransformer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValueTransformer_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and allow classes to be registered. Something like `+ (void)setViewClass:(Class)viewClass forDataClass:(Class)dataClass;`

This is more flexible because you can register these from wherever is easiest for each view and data class. It also uses Class objects rather than strings, which is cleaner and less typo-prone. You can then build a dictionary similar to the one you describe, but with Class objects rather than strings. You can use a Class object just like the class itself. eg. `[[viewClass alloc] init]`.

Incidentally, you don't really need a factory object for this; you can just use a factory method, like `+ (UITableViewCell *)cellForData:(id)data`.

Comment: I though of using `Class` instead of `NSString` however, I'm not sure if the reference to it should be `strong`, `weak` or `unsafe_unretained`. I would say the last. Overall a great answer, thank you. Still, I think the use of a factory object is justified because I can pass it around and it can hold more info about the type of cell, having context, like knowing the identifier before making the cell. Finally , your solution will require to change the transformer if I add another type of cell, which bounds it to the same limitations as the dictionary solution in my question.

Comment: Which doesn't mean is not good of course, but I was hoping to find something that acts like the second solution I proposed, *but* doesn't couple the model with the view.

Comment: You don't need to change the code of the factory to add a new type of cell; you just create a new class for it and call `[CellFactory setViewClass:[MyNewTableViewCell class] forDataClass:[MyNewDataClass class]]` from, say, your app delegate or similar. The CellFactory just keeps a class-level mutable dictionary built from these mappings. So, yes, the dictionary changes, but not the code for your factory.

Comment: Yep, I understand now. I can even make an abstract factory from which all of my factory methods will inherit. The abstract factory will have *all* the mappings. seems like a great idea to be honest. Thank you!